# Making a cron(job) on XAMPP for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cron, xampp

how do I create a cron / cronjob (I am not quite sure about the correct terminology ^^ ) on XAMPP for Mac OS X running Snow Leopard? Or how do I make a cron(job) on Snow Leopard, whether XAMPP or not?

Comment: I strongly recommend cronnix (for Mac):
http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSX has crontab support for running scheduled tasks.

type

```
man crontab
```

In terminal for more information. I also found [this link](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714).

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh: you're free to do so yourself, if you have an updated link. Community edits are always welcome!

Comment: Reily, I don't have the link, and I am want to learn about crontab too.